# correct error code to trace a sphere

Tags: visual-c++, opengl

I have this little code

```
GLUquadricObj *q = gluNewQuadric()
....
.....
glTranslatef(s->c.x, s->c.y, s->c.z);
gluSphere(q, s->r, SPHERE_DIVS, SPHERE_DIVS);
```

and I want to replace this glusphere with a function which I made. It takes as parameters a 3D center, a radium and it traces a sphere

```
int gp21_gluSphere(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z, GLdouble radius);
```

but my problem is that when I replace the function

```
gluSphere(q, s->r, SPHERE_DIVS, SPHERE_DIVS);
```

with

```
gp21_gluSphere (q.x, q.y, q.z, s->r);
```

I get these errors

```
error C2228: left of '.x' must have class/struct/union type
error C2228: left of '.y' must have class/struct/union type
error C2228: left of '.z' must have class/struct/union type
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `q` as a pointer, then are trying to access members like its a Structure / Object.

Try instead:

```
gp21_gluSphere (q->x, q->y, q->z, s->r);
```

Comment: I tried that but I had these errors error C2027: use of undefined type 'GLUquadric'
C:..... : see declaration of 'GLUquadric'
C:\...... error C2227: left of '->x' must point to class/struct/union
 error C2027: use of undefined type 'GLUquadric'
 : see declaration of 'GLUquadric'
error C2227: left of '->y' must point to class/struct/union
 error C2027: use of undefined type 'GLUquadric'
        C:\.... : see declaration of 'GLUquadric'
C:..... error C2227: left of '->z' must point to class/struct/union

Comment: Have you tried actually looking at the definition of `q`?  Why haven't you posted the full and exact definition in your question?

Comment: yes I tried tl look to the definition but I did not succeed to find solution . I didn't post the definition of q because it's a predifined function using q like that : void gluSphere(    GLUquadric* quad,GLdouble radius,GLint slices,GLint stacks );

Specifies    the    quadrics    object    (created    with
       gluNewQuadric()).  Specifies the  radius  of  the  sphere.
       Specifies  the  number  of  subdivisions around the z axis
       (similar to lines of longitude).  Specifies the number  of
       subdivisions  along  the z axis (similar to lines of latitude).